# How are variable assignments detected in a function?

Tags: python, scope, global-variables

When trying to execute the following code:

```py
a = 1
def test_variable():
    if False:
        a = 2
    print(a)

test_variable()
```

It fails with `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment`.

This is in line with how local and global variables work in Python ([source](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python), emphasis mine):

> variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly global. **If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly declared as global.**

However, when disassembling the function's code, I get:

```
  5           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 POP_TOP
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

and we see that there is no trace of a `STORE_FAST` instruction on the variable `a`.

Therefore, I'm wondering how does the interpreter know about the variable assignment if it's not present in the bytecode? Or, to phrase it from the opposite point of view: If the interpreter is smart enough to skip the `if False` block altogether, why doesn't the code execute?

Comment: Even if the code is ultimately eliminated via an optimizing step, as some point the interpreter saw it before that happened. Apparently that's when—after seeing the assignment—that it decided `a` must be a local since it wasn't declared `global` anywhere prior to that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment is detected by the parser, not by the byte-code interpreter. Since it sees an assignment somewhere in the function, it treats `a` as a local variable. The `LOAD_FAST` instruction accesses local variables, and it gets an error because the variable doesn't exist.

Add a `global a` statement and compare the resulting disassembly. I think `LOAD_FAST` will be changed to `LOAD_GLOBAL`.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks :)